# black background in png image in chrome

Tags: image, google-chrome

I have a trouble with displaying my .png images in Chrome - background is black instead of transparent. In Firefox everything is ok. 
What can i do to fix this bug? I tried to write some CSS rules like "background-color: transparent" but nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to force the background to not be transparent by setting it. This seems to be an issue only with Chrome. 
"

Comment: Yep. Seems to be a Chrome thing. I don't see it in IE11, FF69 or Edge44. Just Chrome77 .